# Is it possible to animate region of mkmapview after clicking on button in second vc which is covering map with clear background color?

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiview, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview

all I want to do is to create functionality similar to Find my friends app created by apple for iPhones. I created main view with mapview and then I create other view controller which is displayed on the main screen with backgrond clear color so I can see map in the background. All I want to do now is to change region of displayed annotations. Is there any way to trigger animation from child view controller which is already active?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is fairly straightforward. There are three basic parts.

**First**:
As you've probably noticed, if you add another view controller by using `presentViewController` or `UINavigationController`'s `present…` method, the views behind it are removed from the view hierarchy when the new view is added. You'll see a flash of black as your transparent view moves in.

What you need to do here is add the view controller as a *child* view controller (See Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html) for more info about View Controller Containment).

So, the first step is to use `addChildViewController` to add your view controller, and `addSubview` to add that child's view.

**Second**, you need a means for the second view controller (I'll call them 'A' and 'B') to communicate back to the first ('A'). So, it'll need a reference to it. This is the standard delegate pattern. Probably just initialize your view controller with a method like `initWithFrame:(frame) mapViewController:(id<MyMapViewControllerProtocol>)delegate`.

Then, when the button is pushed, call a method on the delegate. Since the delegate hosts the map, it can do whatever it needs to then. Read up on the delegate pattern for more on this one.

**Third**, if you want the map to be interactive, you're going to find that the view over it captures touches and they never get to the map. Or, if you make it not capture touches, none of the controls on it will work.

To deal with this, make the view a custom subclass of UIView. Here's my TouchTransparentView:

```
#import "TouchTransparentView.h"

@implementation TouchTransparentView

-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return hitView;
    }
}

@end
```